# Can I use a beacon to enter a Journey with my app?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilesdk, mobilepush

I would like to know if I can enter my mobile app users into a journey when they enter the range of a beacon and/or geolocation.

I know you can trigger a push notification via a beacon/geolocation but I have some use cases where I would like to filter some users out of receiving the message. My thoughts were to instead push users into a journey and let journey builder do the filtering then decide wether or not to send the message.

Any help or insights would be appreciated.

Comment: You can push a landing page URL via the beacon.  If the customer goes to the URL, this could then trigger the journey.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the Mobile Push SDK itself cannot trigger a user into a journey; it would need to be an integration of some sort on the back-end (your service to Marketing Cloud) such that the geofence break events kick off an external process which connects back into Marketing Cloud journeys.

Comment: That's what I thought might have to happen. Now to find that external process to tie back into SFMC. I think if the mobile app can write back to a data extension, that would be a trigger to push users into a journey.